# How to proportionally change the weight of a group?

Tags: vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have a weight group generated automatically by a rig. It does seem to be correct, but it is too strong. How can I change the strength of the weight group proportionally for all vertices?

I can do it with a script:

```py
import bpy

# Set the active object
obj = bpy.context.object

# Set the name of the vertex group to modify
vertex_group_name = "Leg-Left"

# Get the vertex group
vertex_group = obj.vertex_groups.get(vertex_group_name)

if vertex_group is None:
    exit()
    
# Iterate through all vertices in the mesh
for v in obj.data.vertices:
    if vertex_group.index not in [g.group for g in v.groups]:
        continue
    
    # Get the weight of the vertex in the vertex group
    weight = vertex_group.weight(v.index)
    
    # Decrease the weight by a factor of 2
    new_weight = weight * 0.5
    
    # Set the new weight for the vertex in the vertex group
    vertex_group.add([v.index], new_weight, 'REPLACE')
```

Can it also be done via Blender's interface without scripting?